# Split terminal in Atom

Tags: terminal, atom-editor

I was curious if it is possible to split the terminal in the Atom text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Command-k followed by an arrow key to indicate the direction to split the pane.  Command-w will close the panes you generated.

For the terminal themselves, the extension term3 supports splitting a terminal window.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Is there a certain extension I need?

Comment: i updated my answer. term3 supports split terminal windows.

Comment: Atom fails to install that for me. Is there another terminal that has similar functionality?

Comment: Did it tell you it didn't install it?  It installed for me but it didn't tell me. I found out by trying the commands.

Comment: It said install failed.